# PHP/jQuery/Javascript - Allow only numbers and some characters in variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

I need to verify if user have entered desired characters in the input field and if he didn't, I need to format input like this:

**Start variable:** `+42 88 66 44 3, +42 (4) 87/654321; +42 3 123456`

**Desired variable:** `+428866443, +42487654321, +423123456`

So basically I need to clear out all characters from variable that are not numbers and allow only signs like `+` `,` `;` `-`.

Because I'm using an AJAX request, I would appreciate code for both PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Is that three separate entries, or *one* entry? And, seriously, have you implemented anything yet? What part are you stuck at?

Comment: I'm sorry, but as HillBilly.Developer said, we're not going to write code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For striping invalid chars from your string use regular expression in PHP and JAVASCRIPT.

**PHP**

```
$s = '+42 88 66 44 3, +42 (4) 87/654321; +42 3 123456';
$n = preg_replace('~[^\d\+,;-]~', '', $s);
print_r($n);
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var s = '+42 88 66 44 3, +42 (4) 87/654321; +42 3 123456';
var n = s.replace(/[^\d\+,;-]/g, "");
console.log(n);
```

But better practice is that you show error, if user enters wrong format. You will need some validating to todo...

Comment: **Escape** the `-` in a character class, or move it to the beginning/end. Eg: `[^\d+,;-]`

Comment: This code, php and js, works for me. I have tested it before posting as an answer. But ok, I have corrected my answer. Tnx

Comment: Sure, I'll notify user what he is allowed to type. Thanks a lot!